# Undefined references while compiling mono on CentOS 6.0

Tags: compilation, mono, compiler-errors, centos

I'm trying to compile Mono myself on Centos6.0. I downloaded the tarball mono-2.10.2.tar.bz2 on the official website. I followed the instructions. The configure command (./configure --prefix=/usr/local) worked good, but I get several undefined references during the linking of the /mono/profiler/mono-cov.c file. For instance I get an undefined reference to monoeg_malloc0.

Does someone know what's happening ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use mono 2.10.8, it has been released a while ago.